# SpeechKit Function Result Called Multiple Times

Tags: swift, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm using SpeechKit to return speech to text into a list. Such as making a grocery's list. But I keep getting multiple values. I don't what's the problem. I know the function is called only once, but it's returning multiple values. Below is a gif of what it looks like and the code. Please give me some guidance.

[image]

```
func prepareAudioEngine() {
    let node = audioEngine.inputNode
    let recordingFormat = node.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    node.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer, _) in
        self.request.append(buffer)
    }

    audioEngine.prepare()
    do {
        try audioEngine.start()
    } catch {
        return print(error)
    }

    guard let myRecogizer = speechRecognizer else { return }

    if !myRecogizer.isAvailable {
        return
    }

    recordandRecognizeSpeech()
}

func recordandRecognizeSpeech() {
    recognitionTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
        if let result = result {
            let stringArray = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
            let size = stringArray.reversed().firstIndex(of: " ") ?? stringArray.count
            let startWord = stringArray.index(stringArray.endIndex, offsetBy: -size)
            let last = stringArray[startWord...]
            self.detectedTextLabel.text = String(last).capitalized

        } else if let error = error {
            print("There was an error",error)
        }

        self.ingredients.append(Ingredient(name: self.detectedTextLabel.text ?? "Default", imageName: ""))
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.ingredients.count - 1, section: 0)
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I think what's going on here is that when `request.shouldReportPartialResults = true`, multiple SFSpeechRecognitionResult's are being returned as the speechRecognizer parses them. Replacing your `recognitionTask` code with the below:

```
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "y-MM-dd H:m:ss.SSSS"
        recognitionTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
            if let result = result {
                let d = Date()
                print(df.string(from: d)) // -> "2016-11-17 17:51:15.1720"
                print("isFinal: \(result.isFinal)")
                for (isegment, segment) in result.bestTranscription.segments.enumerated() {
                    print("\(isegment): \(segment.substring) (ts \(segment.timestamp), dur \(segment.duration), conf \(segment.confidence)")
                }

            } else if let error = error {
                print("There was an error",error)
            }
        })
```

And inspecting the Xcode console output when testing on my iPad...

Here's what I saw when I started the audio engine, said "Hey do", briefly paused (~1 second), then said "you hear me"

```
2020-06-07 17:31:14.0330
isFinal: false
0: Hey (ts 0.0, dur 0.0, conf 0.0)
2020-06-07 17:31:14.2190
isFinal: false
0: Hey (ts 0.0, dur 0.0, conf 0.0)
1: do (ts 0.0, dur 0.0, conf 0.0)
2020-06-07 17:31:14.2560
isFinal: false
0: Hey (ts 0.0, dur 0.0, conf 0.0)
2020-06-07 17:31:14.5600
isFinal: false
0: Hey (ts 0.0, dur 0.0, conf 0.0)
1: do (ts 0.0, dur 0.0, conf 0.0)
2020-06-07 17:31:14.6690
isFinal: false
0: Hey (ts 0.0, dur 0.0, conf 0.0)
1: do (ts 0.0, dur 0.0, conf 0.0)
2020-06-07 17:31:14.7930
isFinal: false
0: Hey (ts 0.55, dur -0.55, conf 0.745)
1: do (ts 0.84, dur -0.84, conf 0.816)
2020-06-07 17:31:15.6900
isFinal: false
0: Hey (ts 0.0, dur 0.0, conf 0.0)
1: do (ts 0.0, dur 0.0, conf 0.0)
2: you (ts 0.0, dur 0.0, conf 0.0)
2020-06-07 17:31:15.8630
isFinal: false
0: Hey (ts 0.0, dur 0.0, conf 0.0)
1: do (ts 0.0, dur 0.0, conf 0.0)
2: you (ts 0.0, dur 0.0, conf 0.0)
3: hear (ts 0.0, dur 0.0, conf 0.0)
2020-06-07 17:31:16.1120
isFinal: false
0: Hey (ts 0.0, dur 0.0, conf 0.0)
1: do (ts 0.0, dur 0.0, conf 0.0)
2: you (ts 0.0, dur 0.0, conf 0.0)
3: hear (ts 0.0, dur 0.0, conf 0.0)
4: me (ts 0.0, dur 0.0, conf 0.0)
2020-06-07 17:31:16.1950
isFinal: false
0: Hey (ts 0.55, dur -0.55, conf 0.93)
1: do (ts 0.84, dur -0.84, conf 0.915)
2: you (ts 1.92, dur -1.92, conf 0.927)
3: hear (ts 2.2800000000000002, dur -2.2800000000000002, conf 0.932)
4: me (ts 2.5100000000000002, dur -2.5100000000000002, conf 0.923)
```

And after waiting for a little bit (~2 seconds), then stopping the audioEngine:

```
2020-06-07 17:31:18.4710
isFinal: false
0: Hey (ts 0.55, dur -0.55, conf 0.93)
1: do (ts 0.84, dur -0.84, conf 0.915)
2: you (ts 1.92, dur -1.92, conf 0.927)
3: hear (ts 2.2800000000000002, dur -2.2800000000000002, conf 0.932)
4: me (ts 2.5100000000000002, dur -2.5100000000000002, conf 0.923)
2020-06-07 17:31:18.5200
isFinal: true
0: Hey (ts 0.55, dur 0.2899999999999999, conf 0.93)
1: do (ts 0.84, dur 0.42000000000000004, conf 0.915)
2: you (ts 1.92, dur 0.3600000000000003, conf 0.927)
3: hear (ts 2.2800000000000002, dur 0.22999999999999998, conf 0.932)
4: me (ts 2.5100000000000002, dur 0.3099999999999996, conf 0.923)
```

Note a few things:

- Timestamps on [SFTranscriptionSegment](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sftranscriptionsegment)s are 0.0 when the `result` is still "being parsed" (or whatever is happening)
- The timestamps all become reasonable values when the parser seems to be happy with them.
- Additional segments are added as more audio is fed in. Those timestamps become valid eventually, and we get a list of tokens with monotonically increasing timestamps, as you'd expect. The timestamps reported from previously-parsed audio segments remain the same.
- the isFinal flag on the `result` is only True when the audioEngine gets stopped.

Unfortunately, I don't see any other flags in the [SFTranscriptionSegment](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sftranscriptionsegment) or [SFSpeechRecognitionResult](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognitionresult) classes that'll help distinguish "still being parsed" from "okay, I'm done with this".

**Recommendation**

For real-time handling of transcription, I'd suggest filtering the results based on their timestamp. Keep an output list of tokens and timestamps (or something) and only add to that when a token arrives with a larger timestamp.

I expect this may break down in the case where the recognitionTask decides towards the end of the full audio segment that it wants to change words from early in the segment. Then you'd get changed tokens and timestamps in the early part of the segment.

For your particular case, it might help to stop the audioEngine if there's a period of silence in the audio, and start it up again. This would force the recognitionTask to finalize its parsing of the audio and ensure the segments/timestamps/tokens don't change.

Comment: Thanks for this! Let me try it out, I never even thought about checking Xcode console output.